# Increasing vertical distance between bibliography items

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, formatting

Numeration in the bibliography looks like

```
1. Book1
2. Book2
```

I want to change it to

```
[1] Book1
[2] Book2
```

Also, I would like to increase a space between separate item.

I'm using the `\begin{thebibliography}` command:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{45}
\bibitem{} Book1
\bibitem{} Book2
\end{}
```

Comment: Can you please add more information? A small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. The default for the standard classes is `[1]`, not `1.`, so it's important to know what class you're using.

Comment: oh sorry, i have coppied code which have changed the numeration, thank you. But how I can increase distance between items?

Comment: Still a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue seems to have been solved by removing some code changing the labels for the bibliography; for the second issue (the vertical spacing between items) you can use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch `\thebibliography`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin\labelwidth\addtolength\itemsep{\baselineskip}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testa} First bibitem.
\bibitem{testb} Second bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The code above will work, at least, for the standard classes (article, book, report); instead of `\baselineskip` you can use any other length (`10pt`, `1ex`, etc.) here:

```
\addtolength\itemsep{\baselineskip}
```

An image of the result:

[image]